# Why fields in same hierarchy get deleted when updating in Prisma?

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I am trying to implement updation using prisma.
here is my data structure.

```
{
  "name":"toy",
  "data":{
     "sports":{
        "currentState":"false",
        "oldState":"true"
    }
     
  }
```

Here is my logic to update `currentState` from `false` to `true`.

```
const updatedSource = await prisma.sources.update({
            where: {
                name: 'toy'
            },
            data: {
                data: {
                   update:{
                       sports: {
                           currentState: "true"
                       }
                   }
                }
            },
        })
```

Here is the schema file:

```
type SourcesData {
  sports        SourcesDataState
}

type SourcesDataState {
  currentState String
  oldState     String
}


model sources {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  data         SourcesData
  name         String   @unique
}
```

The above logic updates the `currentState` field but deletes the `oldState` field from the database.

Please guide me on how to update `currentState` in a way that `oldState` data persists.

Comment: Please share your `schema.prisma`. Is the value of `oldState` deleted in the database or in your variable? You might want to `include` it in the `update` query.

Comment: @some-user The whole ``oldState`` field gets deleted

Comment: You would need to provide both the values of SourcesDataState type, so while updating you would need to pass currentState and oldState both. Otherwise, the new value would be overwritten.